# Is there a way to redirect to an external URL if the user answered a particular choice? SurveyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, surveyjs

I have a radiogroup question in my SurveyJS json, and I want to redirect the user to another page if they choose a particular choice from that question. Otherwise, I want them to keep taking the survey.
Is that possible?

(I'm using react/next.js to build the survey)

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers#redirects-to-a-specified-path-or-url) there is. Create a handler as shown for the survey question you want to react to.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I know how to redirect to a URL with nextjs. What I don't know is how to call a handler or function from the user answer with SurveyJS https://surveyjs.io/documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurveyJs's support helped me with this one:

https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ticket/details/t12269/is-there-a-wayt-to-redirect-the-user-to-another-page-url-when-they-select-a-choice-in